# Unitary matrices with specific properties

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to find two unitary $3\times3$ matrices A and B with AB=-BA? This is certainly possible in $2\times2$ by using \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} and
\begin{pmatrix} 
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
I don't seem to be able to do something like this for the $3\times 3$ case can anybody see an obvious spectrum obstrucion im missing?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would suggest that you see if *any* $3\times3$ matrices satisfy $AB=-BA$. Then, see if there is a similarity transformation which will take your $A$ and $B$ into unitary form. I do not have the time to investigate too far into it, but presumable there is some property of the matrix that tells you if this is possible (for example, if you want to see if a matrix is inverible, then the determinent must be zero; I assume there is a similar condition for a matrix to be unitary, but I am unsure). This method will not find the matrices, but it will tell you they exist.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found an answer it is quite easy to see that the spectrum(and multiplicity of its eigenvalues) of $AB$ is the same as that of $BA$ where if $ABv=\lambda v\ $ then $BA(A^*v)=\lambda A^*v$. Hence writing $\sigma(AB)$ for the spectrum of $AB$ up to multiplicity we have that $\sigma(AB)=\sigma(-BA)=-\sigma(BA)=-\sigma(AB)$ which of course is impossible for a set of size 3 in the unit circle.